# Eigen vector of a non symmetric matrix.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

In my quantum mechanics course, we were finding eigenvalues of a 3 by 3 matrix which was not symmetric. My question is when we find eigenvalues and try to find eigenvectors we have infinite choice of choosing arbitrary values to from a eigenvector of 3 by 1 matrix.

My question is

1. Are these eigenvectors for different eigenvalues linearly independent to each other always. And if not always is there a possible case where they become linearly independent.
2. If suppose there are choices of choosing eigenvector, is there a choice of choosing eigenvector for different eigenvalue chosen to be orthogonal, in spite of  there exist various choices of choosing eigenvector such that some may produce non orthogonal eigenvector.

Edit. If possible go easy on me if my question is absurd and if possible, can explain by an example of a simple 3 by 3 matrix would be kind of you.

Comment: To put it briefly, eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvectors are always linearly independent, but there are even $2\times 2$ cases where they cannot be chosen orthogonal

Comment: Why is it so that they are linearly independent. what makes them, or is just that we always need to check whether they are or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Few useful points**:

1. If matrix $(A)_{n\times n}$ has distinct eigenvalues then there always exist $n$ LI eigenvectors. Though for repeated eigenvalues you have to try your luck as the answer is not always positive unless $A$ is symmetric matrix.
2. There always exist an orthogonal set of LI eigenvectors (*in addition to some non-orthogonal set too*) for a symmetric matrix $A$.

**Added-**

3. If the eigenvectors are orthogonal then  matrix $A$ is necessarily symmetric.The proof is as follows:

Let $P$ be the modal matrix (orthogonal) corresponding to matrix $A$ s.t. $A=PDP^{T}$, where $D$ is diagonal matrix with eigenvalues in its diagonal. Then $A^T=(PDP^T)^T=PDP^T=A$

Comment: Can you just give one example in a matrix form, where a matrix is not symmetric but its eigenvector are still orthogonal. And also does a non symmetric matrix generally have linear independent eigenvector for degenerate eigenvalues.

Comment: For orthogonal eigenvectors, the matrix is always symmetric. See the added part is answer.

Comment: i understood it for symmetric. But my question is does a orthogonal matrix exist for non-symmetric matrix.

Comment: No. The possibility is ruled out due to the proof in (3).

Comment: So atlast can we conclude that for eigenvector to be orthogonal, the matrix must be symmetric or hermitian.

Comment: yes.......…..........….................…

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when dealing with finite dimensional vector spaces the set of vectors formed by choosing one eigenvector for each eigenvalue is
always linearly independent. It is one of the first results you will find while studying those topics, and the proof can be found in almost any Linear Algebra book (I can recommend you looking for *Foundations of Linear Algebra* by J. Golan, p. 130).

I suppose the entries of your matrices are real numbers; if your $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ is diagonalizable, i.e. if you can find a basis of the vector space $R^3$ whose elements are all eigenvectors of $A$ (i.e. if you can find a basis $D$ of $R^3$ for which the matrix representation of $L_A$ is diagonal), then by the [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20particularly%20linear%20algebra,with%20the%20standard%20inner%20product.) you can indeed
obtain from this basis an orthonormal basis of the space. The bad news is that this new basis is not necessarily formed by eigenvectors
of the matrix anymore.
Indeed, there is a theorem that states that the fact of finding an orthogonal basis $D$ of $V$ (where $V$ is a finite-dimensional
real inner product space) consisting of eigenvectors of a linear operator $T:V \rightarrow V$ *is equivalent* to the fact
of $T$ being self adjoint.

Comment: I got it now. It will be different. For my 2nd part can you comment on it, that there exist a choice of choosing eigenvector to be orthogonal or does orthogonal eigenvector exist only for symmetric matrix only.

Comment: Maybe you can find two eigenvectors that are orthogonal; I understand that your question is *When can we find an orthogonal basis consisting of eigenvectors of the given matrix?*; as I wrote above, this can only be made when the linear operator $L_A$ is self adjoint; if I'm not wrong, in your context of matrices with real entries, this is is the same thing as $A$ being symmetric, yes.

Comment: What if the entries of matrices are real numbers say, but the matrix is not symmetric?

Comment: @AnshulSharma by Spectral Theorem, 
a real matrix $A$ is symmetric if and only if there exists an orthogonal basis made of eivenvectors